# Cant Increase Android Studio's Memory Heap

Tags: android, android-studio, heap-memory

I am using latest version of Android studio 1.3 preview beta release. But it is working very slow on my system (RAM 4GB). When i try to edit a java or xml file in editor it takes 3-4 second to write a word. I have followed [this](http://geek.moneylover.me/android-studio-eliminate-shutter-n-lag/) blog to Increase Android Studio's Memory Heap size. I have updated the studio64.exe.vmoptions file at path C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe Here is what inside my vmoptions file:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioPreview1.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

But my android studio memory heap remains same after changes in file. Here is screen shot it is still 512m:

[image]

Please suggest any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

This file is ignored from Android Studio.

On Windows your path to update is

- `%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio.exe.vmoptions`
- `%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

For more - [Android Tools Documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration)

Comment: I have three folders in Userprofile path .AndroidStudio, .AndroidStudio1.2 and .AndroidStudioPreview1.3 , they contains subfolders (config,restart and system) but i cant find studio.exe.vmoptions or studio64.exe.vmoptions file in any of them

Comment: The very first sentence at [Android Tools Docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) explains what to do. If you don't have `.vmoptions`, just create a file with expected name/extension and add your values there.

Comment: thanks for response, but i have three folders in it cofig, restart and system in which folder should i create .vmoptions file?

Comment: I am on a Mac so guessing here. Create the `exe..vmoptions` file and place it in any folder where you have `studio.exe` or `studio64.exe`. This need to be **only** in `.AndroidStudioPreview1.3`. You can delete `.AndroidStudio` and `.AndroidStudioPreview1.2` - they are just leftovers from previous versions of Android Studio you used to have before updating in time.

Comment: FYI to other readers coming here, as mentioned in jayeffkay's later answer, on Windows the location of user-modified files will be under your user name (NOT the one in Program Files). You can see the exact path by opening a Command Prompt, and type "Set" to list the environment variables. In the response, look for USERPROFILE. Typically `C:\Users\YourUserName`. Add new file to folder for your version, e.g. `C:\Users\YourUserName\.Androidstudio2.1`  (By default, the file `studio.exe.vmoptions` or `studio64.exe.vmoptions` for 64-bit will not yet exist.)

Answer (score 0):

I am on Windows 7 64bit, and there you should place `studio64.exe.vmoptions` directly under `<user>.AndroidStudio1.3`, much like @DimitarGenov states. Then restart AS.